# preventing player for getting refreshed when present in footer in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a player in a footer tag in two pages in html.
when ever i am trying to go to another page the player is getting refreshed (or footer) and it stops playing . i am using jquery mobile. please help me out

Comment: Each page has its own footer so when you move from one page to another, you would get the other footer. What exactly are you trying to do?